# Dispose is not being called

Tags: flutter

I've got a stateful Widget that's on the navigation stack; HomeScreen()
For some reason, when it should be removed from the stack, it doesn't appear to be calling dispose().

I remove HomeScreen from the navigation stack in two ways:
**1)** Using Navigator.pushReplacement()

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    PageRouteBuilder(
                        pageBuilder: (context, a1, a2) => GroupScreen()));
```

**2)** Using Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil()

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LandingScreen()),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

The dispose method in HomeScreen() is overridden with the following:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    print("dispose called");
    _timer.cancel();
    print('Timer has been disposed');
    super.dispose();
  }
```

and it's apparent that it's not being called as the print statements are not output to the console.

It may be worth mentioning that the HomeScreen has a StreamBuilder, but I'm not too sure if that would impact things.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you please update the question with your ```HomeScreen``` code ?

Comment: there's a related open issue being discussed on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40940

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it turns out that I was using "MaterialApp" for one of the widgets in the build method rather than "Material", which was causing the issue.